# HTTP CORS requests with credentials are failing using Axios

Tags: typescript, http, axios, asmx

I have a legacy webforms asp.net website and a new asp.net core site sharing an auth cookie. When I try to make a CORS HTTP request from `Typescript` (in the core site) to a Web Service method (in the legacy site) using `Axios` it fails *unless* I pass an empty data object. For example:

This request will **fail**:

```
    const url: string = "http://legacy.mydev.machine:1259/MyService.asmx/GetInformation";
    const optionsThatWontWork: AxiosRequestConfig = {
        withCredentials: true
    };
    axios.get(url, optionsThatWontWork)
        .then((response) => { console.log(response); })
        .catch((error) => { console.log(error); });
```

The browser does 1 HTTP GET (no pre-flight) request that returns an HTTP 500 with the following message in the response

> "Request format is unrecognized for URL unexpectedly ending in '/GetInformation'."

But this **works**:

```
    const url: string = "http://legacy.mydev.machine:1259/MyService.asmx/GetInformation";
    const optionsThatWillWork: AxiosRequestConfig = {
        withCredentials: true,
        data: {
            // Adding this empty data object makes a difference
        }
    };
    axios.get(url, optionsThatWillWork)
        .then((response) => { console.log(response); })
        .catch((error) => { console.log(error); });
```

In this case the browser makes 2 requests. The first is an HTTP OPTIONS request that return with a 200 then the second is a GET that successfully hits the `GetInformation` endpoint and returns a 200 with the json data.

When comparing the 2 HTTP GET messages the only difference that I can see is that the successful one has a `Content-Type: application/json;charset=utf-8` header.

I tried adding in that header manually but that didn't work either:

```
    const optionsThatStillWontWork: AxiosRequestConfig = {
        withCredentials: true,
        headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/json;charset=utf-8"
        },
    };
```

I have configured CORS in the legacy site's `Owin` pipeline using `Microsoft.Owin.Cors`:

```
Private Sub ConfigureCors(ByVal app As IAppBuilder)
    Dim corsPolicy = New CorsPolicy() With {
        .AllowAnyMethod = True,
        .AllowAnyHeader = True,
        .SupportsCredentials = True,
        .AllowAnyOrigin = False
    }

    corsPolicy.Origins.Add("http://newsite.mydev.machine:9050")

    Dim corsPolicyProvider = New CorsPolicyProvider With {
        .PolicyResolver = Function(context) Task.FromResult(corsPolicy)
    }

    Dim options = New CorsOptions With {
        .PolicyProvider = corsPolicyProvider
    }

    app.UseCors(options)
End Sub
```

*Note: both `http://legacy.mydev.machine:1259` and `http://newsite.mydev.machine:1259` have entries in my hosts file pointing to `127.0.0.1`.*

According to [the axios documentation](https://github.com/axios/axios) the `data` config option is

> "Only applicable for request methods 'PUT', 'POST', and 'PATCH'"

... which I would agree with.

Couple of questions then:

1. Why does adding the empty `data` object make this work?
2. Why does the first example not do a pre-flight?
3. Does my CORS setup in the legacy site look ok?

Comment: The CORS setup in the question looks fine, and the error message cited in the question are CORS errors has nothing to do with the CORS config. It’s an unrelated error

Answer (score 2):

It seems to an issue in server-side code.

1. Probably it's because of `Content-Type` added automatically because `data` is provided. Even for GET request that does not send payload.
2. Preflight is not sent for ["simple" request](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS#Simple_requests). GET query without any headers outside of whilelist does not require sending preflight.
3. root cause is not related to CORS(since it returns 200 OK in "special" flow and since it is not touched at all in "normal" flow)

I think it make sense to check you controller code that handles request. Assume there should be content type explicitly specified.

BTW if CORS preflight failed there would be no 500 Internal Server Error for GET request. OPTIONS preflight would fail and there would be no GET request on next move.